# How to calculate the gradient for nce_loss in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I need to calculate the gradient of a tensorflow that is stored. I can restore the graph and weights using:

```
    model1 = tf.train.import_meta_graph("models/model.meta")
    model1.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("models/"))
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()

    weights = graph.get_tensor_by_name("weights:0")
    biases = graph.get_tensor_by_name("biases:0")
```

I have also named my loss function in the original function so I can restore it with

```
    loss = graph.get_operation_by_name("loss") # for operation
    loss = graph.get_tensor_by_name("loss:0") # for the tensor
```

Basically, I want to get the gradient of the loss with a certain input value using tf.gradients(...). My loss is specifically the `nce_loss` https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/nce_loss. I want the gradient of the loss given the inputs function. Specifically, I plug in a new embedding and I want the gradient given that new input and the loss function. However I can't seem to define my input successfully. If I use:

```
grads = tf.gradients(loss, loss.inputs) #here I use the tensor loss definition
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/fgsm.py", line 168, in <module>
    main(config)
  File "/tmp/fgsm.py", line 114, in main
    loss = graph.get_operation_by_name("loss:0")
  File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3618, in get_operation_by_name
    return self.as_graph_element(name, allow_tensor=False, allow_operation=True)
  File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3490, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3544, in _as_graph_element_locked
    (repr(name), types_str))
ValueError: Name 'loss:0' appears to refer to a Tensor, not a Operation.
```

How do I define my gradient here?

Comment: Have you tried using `loss = graph.get_operation_by_name("loss")` in tf.gradinets()?

Comment: yes I have, I get another type of error message complaining that loss is not a tensor but an operation (the method requires a tensor)

Comment: Can you please provide full error trace?

Comment: updated the question with the whole error trace

Comment: Have you tried https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/get_losses function?